# node-gyp error for karma

Tags: node.js, npm, karma-runner

Hi I'm trying to install karma using npm. The packages are fetched and the terminal hangs on the last build error message.

Installation

```
npm install -g karma
```

Console log

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/di
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/0.6.0-1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/q
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/log4js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/useragent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/di
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/0.6.0-1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/q
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/log4js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/useragent
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io

> chokidar@0.8.1 postinstall /home/ashwini/.nvm/v0.10.24/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar
> node setup-deps.js

>npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.16
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.1.15
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utile
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.14
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uid2/0.0.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/base64id/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/policyfile/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client/0.9.16
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async/0.1.15
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/utile
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/i
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.14
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.2.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uid2/0.0.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js/1.2.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ws
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlhttprequest/1.4.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/active-x-obfuscator/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/i
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan

ws@0.4.31 install /home/ashwini/.nvm/v0.10.24/lib/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
```

I quickly skimmed through the issues [listed](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/1126) but those didn't help.

Just for additional information:
*Node : v0.10.25*
*NPM : v1.3.26*

Comment: Is this the entire NPM log? I don't see any error in there...

Comment: @Vojta - The error is on the last line: `(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)`

Unfortunately, I am also getting this error.  I have found builderror.log but it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

are you on a windows computer? if so, setting your environment before you run the command might help of you've already installed MSVS.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\bin\SetEnv.CMD" /Release /x64
```